# Unable to connect to chromebrowser 78 in selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run my first selenium test and failed invoking the browser due to port issue. My chrome browser version is Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) and i have downloaded Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70. I see the below error when i run my script.

> Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70
>   (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800})
>   on port 30211 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports
>   used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by
>   malicious code. [1573154573.453][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to
>   Chrome, retrying... Nov 07, 2019 7:22:56 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
>   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97) Build info: version: '3.141.59',
>   revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

I have downloaded the latest chromedriver exe which is compatible with my chromebrowser version.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //invoke browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                "C:\\Users\\270816\\Documents\\Selenium- 
                installations\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        //create browser object
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

        //hit google.com
        driver.get("www.bbc.co.uk");
```

Error message:

> Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70
>   (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800})
>   on port 30211 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports
>   used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by
>   malicious code.

Comment: the ports message is normal... ignore that.  If you never see Chrome launch, check the install path... you may need to set that if it's not in a default directory.

Comment: My script launches the browser but not able to enter the url where it throws the error.

Comment: ahh, ok, use a full URL and check again... with "https://"

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
[1573154573.453][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying... 
Nov 07, 2019 7:22:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97) Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

As per the error stack trace it's inconclusive about actual reason for the error. However as you are using:

- *Selenium v3.141.59*
- *ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70*
- *chrome=78.0.3904.97*

I suspect the issue is with the *JDK* version on the *Test System*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.